# Jetpack Compose draw on image with Painter

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

With painter it's possible to draw on ImageBitmap with the snippet

```
   val imageBitmap: ImageBitmap = imageResource(id = R.drawable.landscape3)

    val customPainter = remember {
        object : Painter() {

            override val intrinsicSize: Size
                get() = Size(imageBitmap.width.toFloat(), imageBitmap.height.toFloat())

            override fun DrawScope.onDraw() {
                drawImage(imageBitmap)
                drawLine(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    start = Offset(0f, 0f),
                    end = Offset(imageBitmap.width.toFloat(), imageBitmap.height.toFloat()),
                    strokeWidth = 5f
                )
            }
        }
    }
    Image(painter = customPainter, contentDescription = null)
```

> loadFontResource is deprecated. Use fontResource instead.
> imageResource, loadImageResource, vectorResource, and
> loadVectorResource are deprecated. Use painterResource instead.
> (I6b809)

with **alpha12**  `imageResource` is deprecated. `painter`'s `drawImage(imageBitmap)` function that draws image has no replacement or another function other than the one takes imageBitmap as parameter?

What's the point of ImageBitmap as of alpha12 since there is no not deprecated function to create it with a resource, and function to get ImageBitmap from Painter does not exist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

starting from [Compose UI 1.0.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.0.0-beta01)

> imageResource and vectorResource are now extension functions on ImageBitmap and ImageVector companions respectively. load{Image,Vector,Font}Resource functions have been deleted. (I89130)

```
import androidx.compose.ui.res.imageResource
// ...
val imageBitmap: ImageBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.landscape3)
```

<strike>**painterResource** under the hood calls [imageFromResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/package-summary#imagefromresource), so we can use it too:</strike>

```
  val imageBitmap: ImageBitmap = imageFromResource(
    LocalContext.current.resources,
    R.drawable.landscape3
  )
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like this is the one to be used to create imageBitmap.

Comment: As of beta01 it's gone i guess. Isn't there a compose way to get an ImageBitmap from resources, or drawables?

Comment: @Thracian It's extension function `imageResource` now.

Answer (score 5):

if you need set ImageVector from drawable folder use:

```
ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_example)
```

ic_example is vector ".xml" file added from svg file

Answer (score 2):

I use this method to use bitmap or SVG

```
Image(
    painterResource(id = R.drawable.video),
    contentDescription = "",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

with Compose 1.0 stable and above, you should use

`useResource("image.png") { loadImageBitmap(it) }`

this will return a `ImageBitmap` object.

There is also `painterResource("image.png")` but this will return a `Painter` object.